# Disable and visually forbid button that opens modal dialog

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap in conjunction with AngularJS. In my application, a link is used to open a modal dialog (using the [data attributes](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#via-data-attributes) concept). I would like to disable the button depending on a state variable or function.

The problem is, AngularJS still executes the function `doSomething()` defined in `ng-click`, even if the button is `ng-disabled`. I can overcome this issue by implementing a guard, that basically checks the same variable as used in the `ng-disabled` attribute. This prevents the code in `ng-click` from being executed (well, technically it is executed, but my function will not trigger).

However, the modal dialog will still open, because the `data-*` attributes do not respect the value of `ng-disabled`. Instead, they rely on the CSS class `disabled`. I can also set that CSS class using `ng-class`. Are you still with me? :-)

**Currently, my code looks like this:**

```
<a href="#showModalDialog" class="btn btn-success btn-md" ng-class="{ 'disabled': !isSomeState() }" data-toggle="modal"
  ng-click="!isSomeState() || doSomething()" ng-disabled="!isSomeState()">
  <span class="fa fa-foobar"></span>
</a>
```

Bootstrap's CSS class `disabled` will set `pointer-events: none;` which is fine for the clicking. The modal dialog will no longer open, when the button is disabled. But Bootstrap used to change the mouse pointer to a *forbidden* sign on disabled user controls. When `pointer-events: none;` is set, however, the mouse pointer will no longer change. This breaks the consistency of my user interface.

Is there any solution for that? I would like to have

- the button visually disabled,
- it should have a *forbidden* sign as a pointer on mouse-over,
- the `ng-click` should not execute my function when the button is disabled
- and furthermore the modal dialog should not open.

And since it's Christmas today, I'm looking for a **simple solution**, i.e. I do not want to rewrite major parts of neither Bootstrap nor AngularJS. I have a lot of these modal dialogs

Comment: if its a bootstrap model then it will cover the entire page by default, you don't have to disable button as it will be beneath the model, so is there a point in disabling visually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a button element instead of an anchor?

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-md"
    data-target="#showModalDialog" data-toggle="modal"
    ng-click="doSomething()" ng-disabled="!isSomeState()">
    <span class="fa fa-foobar"></span>
</button>
```

Of course, if you're relying on the URL to change, you'll have to include that in your JS now instead of using href.

Comment: Dang, it's as easy as that? Works like a charm. I slightly altered your code, so I can accept your answer. Thank you.